# Additional sprite UVs when rendering sprites in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sprite

I have sprites in an atlas rendering in OpenGL properly with the code below. My problem comes from trying to add a secondary "texture" to sample so I can do some multitexturing magic. The problem I think it's that the second sprite is also in an atlas and it's being affected by the VAO offsets so I can't really pick the right UVs to get the exact point I need. I've tried adding some calculations to reverse engineer the correct UVs for this sprite inside the other texture (you can see my attempt at the bottom) but this doesn't seem to work. What would be the best approach to do this?

Preparation:

```
glm::vec4 fRect;

fRect.x = static_cast<float>(iRect.x) / textureWidth;
fRect.y = static_cast<float>(iRect.y) / textureHeight;
fRect.z = (static_cast<float>(iRect.z) / textureWidth) + fRect.x;
fRect.w = (static_cast<float>(iRect.w) / textureHeight) + fRect.y;

// Configure VAO/VBO
GLuint VBO;
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Pos      // Tex
    0.0f, 1.0f, fRect.x, fRect.w,
    1.0f, 0.0f, fRect.z, fRect.y,
    0.0f, 0.0f, fRect.x, fRect.y,
    0.0f, 1.0f, fRect.x, fRect.w,
    1.0f, 1.0f, fRect.z, fRect.w,
    1.0f, 0.0f, fRect.z, fRect.y
};

GLuint VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Rendering:

```
// Prepare transformations
glm::mat4 modelMatrix;
modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, position);
// modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, -glm::vec3(spriteOffset.x, spriteOffset.y, 0.0f));
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, rotate.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
// modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, rotate.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, rotate.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(-spriteOffset.x, -spriteOffset.y, 0.0f));
modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(size, 1.0f));
//(...)
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation, 1, false, glm::value_ptr( modelMatrix ) );
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLocation, 1, false, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix));
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, 1, false, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
ASSERT( !HasOpenGLErrors(), "OpenGL error!" );

glUniform3f(multColorLocation, multColour.x, multColour.y, multColour.z );
glUniform3f(addColorLocation, addColour.x, addColour.y, addColour.z );
ASSERT( !HasOpenGLErrors(), "OpenGL error!" );
// Bind Texture, etc
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 position, vec2 texCoords>

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 model_matrix, view_matrix, projection_matrix;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = vec2(vertex.z, 1.0 - vertex.w);
    gl_Position = projection_matrix*view_matrix*model_matrix*vec4(vertex.xyz,1);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec3 multColour;
uniform vec3 addColour;

void main()
{
    vec4 minColour = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 maxColour = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    vec4 texColour = texture(texture, TexCoords);
    if(texColour.a < 0.01)
        discard;
    color = clamp(vec4(multColour, 1.0) * texColour + vec4(addColour,0.0), minColour, maxColour);
}
```

Failed attempt at reading the right UVs in fragment shader:

```
float normU = (TexCoords.x - currUVs.x) / (currUVs.z - currUVs.x);
float icU = mix(icUVs.x, icUVs.z, normU);
float normV = (TexCoords.y - currUVs.y) / (currUVs.w - currUVs.y);
float icV = mix(icUVs.y, icUVs.w, normV);

vec2 UV = vec2(icU, icV );
vec4 initial = texture(initialColor, UV);
```

Where `currUVs` are the values of `fRect` passed in the VAO above and the `icUVs` are the UV bounds (min and max values) for the second sprite within the atlas texture.

So far it seems like all sprites that have no offset applied will render properly but if I passed in any kind of `spriteOffset` into the rendering, then it will render wrong.

How can I solve this? Is there a way of applying the VAO rects in the shaders and then be able to get the second sprite correctly?

Comment: Why can't you just put two sets of texture coordinates in the VAO?

Comment: Why on earth people downvoted the question? I see nothing wrong with it.